# Is the mapping class group of a surface virtually torsion-free?

Tags: group-theory, surfaces, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

Question:
Is the mapping class group of a surface virtually torsion-free?

Context: The mapping class group of the $ n $ punctured disk is the braid group $ B_n $. The braid group is torsion-free and thus virtually torsion-free. The mapping class group of the torus is $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ which is virtually torsion-free and indeed virtually free (has an index 12 free subgroup https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43726/the-free-group-f-2-has-index-12-in-sl2-mathbbz). Note that braid groups are not virtually free, except $ B_2 \cong \mathbb{Z} $, see [Subgroups of the braid groups $\mathcal{B}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/subgroups-of-the-braid-groups-mathcalb-n) .

Comment: Yes. It should be in pretty much any book on mapping class group. Take the kernel of the action on surface homology mod 3.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike why does taking the kernel of the action on surface homology mod 2 not quite work? Like for the torus that gives you a group $ F_2 \times C_2 $ which is obviously very close to being free but not quite free. Whereas, if we take $ MCG(T^2)=SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ mod larger number we get $ F_3 $ mod 3, $ F_5 $ mod 4, $ F_{11} $ mod $ 5 $ and $ F_\infty $ mod anything bigger.

Comment: It is because of hyperelliptic involutions: They act trivially mod 2.